# adding parameters to tweepy api request

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

How does one set the parameters for a request to twitter via tweepy's api.

```
#https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?exclude_replies=true&include_rts=false
import tweepy

#assume tokens and secrets are declared

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

status = api.user_timeline('xxxxxxxxx')
```

What I get back from this is the "tweets and retweets" from the user inside a collection of Status objects, but
I only want the user's "tweets" returned. After reading the [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#tweepy-api-twitter-api-wrapper), it's still unclear to me on how to modify the request url

Answer (score 1):

I've found success just filtering the json object returned from `user_timeline`.

This will filter out the user's retweets:

```
for tweetObj in status:
    if hasattr(tweetObj, 'retweeted_status'):
        continue
    else:        
        print tweetObj #or whatever else you want to do
```

But to answer your question, you can pass the optional parameter, `include_retweets` like so:

```
status = api.user_timeline('xxxxxxxxx', include_retweets=False)
```

I like the first method better because the RTs still count against your `count` & `maximum length` parameters.